# How to copy files from a txt file to a directory

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd, copy, directory

I really hope you can help me. I have a list with ROMs that I can run in coinops (old Xbox emulator). Its a text file. And I have a file with more than 10000 ROMs in it. I am looking for a batch command that can copy the ROMs that listed in the text file. Here is some info.

Place where the ROMs are:

F:\roms\

Place where the text file is:

F:\coinops\

Name of the text file:

Coinopslist.txt

Place where the roms need to go:

F:\coinops\roms\

It would be so awesome if someone can help me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to make your batch for you but here is an example of how you can

```
C:\Users\Gebruiker>echo log.txt > files_to_copy.txt
C:\Users\Gebruiker>for /F %a in (files_to_copy.txt) do copy "%a" c:\Temp\

C:\Users\Gebruiker>copy "log.txt" c:\Temp\
        1 bestand(en) gekopieerd.
```

For anything more fancy I suggest you learn a scripting language like [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), it's easy to learn and fun using.